# How to make relative path DNS query with dig?

Tags: dns, resolve, dig

I want to make a relative path DNS query with `dig`. I have referenced the following documentation for `dig(1)` and `resolv.conf(5)`.

[dig(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dig) says:

> +ndots=D
>
> Set the number of dots that have to appear in name to D for it to be considered absolute. The default value is that defined using
>   the ndots statement in /etc/resolv.conf, or 1 if no ndots statement is
>   present. Names with fewer dots are interpreted as relative names and
>   will be searched for in the domains listed in the search or domain
>   directive in /etc/resolv.conf.

[resolv.conf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html) says:

> domain Local domain name.
>
> Most queries for names within this domain can use short names relative
>   to the local domain.  If set to '.', the root domain is considered. 
>   If no domain entry is present, the domain is determined from the local
>   hostname returned by gethostname(2); the domain part is taken to be
>   everything after the first '.'. Finally, if the hostname does not
>   contain a domain part, the root domain is assumed.

My `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
options timeout:2 attempts:3 rotate single-request-reopen
; generated by /usr/sbin/dhclient-script
domain nonexist.com
nameserver 100.100.2.136
nameserver 100.100.2.138
```

But running `dig abc` on a `CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core) 64 bit OS` results:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-9.P2.el7 <<>> abc
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 13347
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;abc.               IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
abc.            9080    IN  SOA ac1.nstld.com. info.verisign-grs.com. 1573282493 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 100.100.2.136#53(100.100.2.136)
;; WHEN: Sat Nov 09 15:23:42 CST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 99
```

My expection is that `abc` should be suffixed with `nonexist.com.` and `abc.nonexist.com.` is used in the DNS query. But the above `QUESTION SECTION` has `abc.` instead of `abc.nonexist.com.`

Can anyone point out what is wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[dig(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dig) says:

> **+[no]search**
>
> Use [do not use] the search list defined by the searchlist or domain directive in resolv.conf (if any). The search list is not
>   used by default